# Как правильно посчитать количество вхождений буквы в строке?

Tags: pascal

Этот код должен считать кол-во вхождений буквы `а` в коде, но у меня не получается правильно написать этот алгоритм, я знаю в чем ошибка, но не знаю как это исправить.

```
Program hackerman228;
begin;
var line:string;
var countA, countB, i:integer;
write('Введите предложение: ');
read(line);
for i:=0 to line.Length-1 do
  begin
    if (pos('а', copy(line, i+1, line.Length - i -1)) > 0) then 
    begin
      countA:= countA + 1;
    end;
  end;
write('Кол-во слов начинающихся на букву а: ', countA);
end.
```

Comment: "я знаю в чем ошибка" - нам скажете?

Comment: pos('а', copy(line, i+1, line.Length - i -1)

Comment: countA:= countA + 1; 
А присвоить начальное значение счётчику? По существу же 
if line[i] = 'a' then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замысловатый метод, но так и быть:

```
if Pos('а', Copy(line, i + 1, 1)) = 1 then
```

---

```
if 'а' = line[i + 1] then
```

Comment: Занудства ради, я там ещё `countA := 0` не увидел. Ну и если сделать `for i:=1 to line.Length do`, то не нужно будет писать `line[i + 1]`, а просто `line[i]`. И ещё: в исходном задании написано "считать кол-во вхождений буквы", а программа выводит: "Кол-во слов начинающихся на букву а:", что не верно.

Answer (score 1):

Инициализацию Var вытащи за пределы Begin:

```
var line:string;
    countA, countB, i:integer;
Begin....
```